# How do I search an element in shell script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, search, sed

I have an array

declare -a fruits=("apple" "banana" "guava" "cherry" "mango"  "litchi")

I need to write a shell script, it can take multiple arguments (comma separated). It should check each argument against the array- fruits in case argument doesn't match it should exit stating argument is not in array. It should return all the invalid arguments

E.g ./dummy.sh carrot,potato,cabbage

o/p: carrot,potato,cabbage not found in array

e.g 2 ./dummy.sh banana,mango
o/p banana,mango found in list

Comment: I am trying the following: I am trying following:

for i in $(echo "${arguments}" | sed "s/,/ /g") ; do    
 flag=0    
           for j in "${fruits[@]}"; do        
        if [ "$i" == "$j" ]       
                  then       
         flag=1       
                  break        
              else    
               arr=i     
              fi    
       done    
 if [ "$flag" != 1 ]    
        then    
               echo "$arr not found in array"        
    fi    
done

Comment: Why should the argument be a comma separated list? That is not idiomatic shell.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash    
declare -a fruits=("apple" "banana" "guava" "cherry" "mango" "litchi")

IFS=, read -ra args <<< "$1"
for arg in "${args[@]}"
do
   #echo "Searching for $arg"
   found=0
   for fruit in "${fruits[@]}"
   do
      if [[ $fruit == $arg ]]; then found=1; break; fi
   done
   if [[ $found == 0 ]]; then echo "$arg is not found"; break; fi
done
```